# How to display a label only when an input is focused

Tags: html, css

Label is covering my input. After I click input I still want to see label with **`Dupsko`** content, but over my input.

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(38, 50, 56, 0.31);
    transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1);
}

label {
    padding-left: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: text;
    z-index: -10;
}

input {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background-image: none;
    background-color:  transparent;

    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #263238;;
    transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1);
}

input:focus {
    background-color: #263238;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #3FBA84;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

input:focus ~ label {
    position: unset;
    color: #3FBA84;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Dupsko</label>
  <input>
</div>
```

How can I apply styles to this label only if input is focused ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input:focus ~ label` selects every `label` element that are preceded by an `input:focus` element. So you need to change the order of two elements in your html. Also, I moved the

```
position: absolute;
```

from `label` to `input` so that the `input` will be stacked on top of the `label`.

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(38, 50, 56, 0.31);
    transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1);
}

label {
    padding-left: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: text;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

input {
    position: absolute;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background-image: none;
    background-color:  transparent;

    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #263238;;
    transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1);
}

input:focus {
    background-color: #263238;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #3FBA84;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: -1;
}

input:focus ~ label {
    position: unset;
    color: #FFFF;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input><label>Dupsko</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS you can only select siblings which come *after* an element.

If you want to select previous siblings but have them ordered (visually) label first, then input, you could set the parent div to:

```
display: flex; 
flex-direction: column-reverse;
```

then swap the label and input in the HTML so you can select it with `~`:

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(38, 50, 56, 0.31);
    transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1);
}

label {
    padding-left: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: text;
    z-index: -10;
}

input {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background-image: none;
    background-color:  transparent;

    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #263238;;
    transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1);
}

input:focus {
    background-color: #263238;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #3FBA84;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

input:focus ~ label {
    position: unset;
    color: #3FBA84;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input>
  <label>Dupsko</label>
</div>
```